# Cast to ObjectId failed for value | Mongodb Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch only the users posts, and i'm using this code:

```
router.get("/:username", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username });
    const posts = await Post.find({ userId: user._id });
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

I'm using Postman for testing GET `localhost:6000/posts/admin` and every time I try it, it gives this error

> ```
> "name": "CastError",
> "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"admin\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Post\""
> ```

This is my posts collection in Monogodb

[image]

And this is the users collection in Mongodb

[image]

I don't know what i'm missing here, I just want the link posts/:username shows the posts of this username only

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this code is throwing this error? Is there some middleware or another match that happens before this controller?

Comment: yes, I deleted all the codes in my router and kept only this code and it still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username });
```

This query finds user but user._id comes as object but in your db userId saved as a string so you should probably save userId as object

```
const blogSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    userId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }, //Example
});
```